# Setting initial state based on prop when using useState Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to set the initial state of a child component to the prop value passed down by the parent.

```
export default (props) => {
  const myValueFromProp = props;
  const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState(myValueFromProp);

  return (
    <Text>
     {myValue}
    </Text>
  );
};
```

Above is the code I have come up with. I am confused to whether this is the correct approach i should be following.

> There is more state based logic inside this particular component which
>   i have omitted for simplicity sake.

Comment: you can pass like <Text myValue={myValue}/>

Comment: There is more state based logic inside this particular component which i have omitted for simplicity sake.

Comment: Yeah that's the right approach.

Comment: Initial state is what you pass inside the `useState` function, so yes! you are doing it correctly. Is there a reason why you're setting the props in state?

Comment: My project is a react native project. I am actually trying to pass a parameter as a prop when navigating between screens. The second screen would have some logic such as data fetching, viewing certain components etc based on the prop passed from the first screen. Once the second screen is rendered it would no longer depend on the props passed by the first screen. This is because the first screen is where we navigated away from so it no longer exists unless we press back.

Comment: If your second screen component is being rendered by the first screen. How could the first screen no longer exist? Unless your second screen is being rendered by something else. Anyway this is usually an anti-pattern. This almost never really necessary. Props should usually remain as props.This reading might help you: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Comment: @cbdev420 its not rendered by the first screen . Its rendered when i navigate away from the first screen right  ? Im using react navigtion.

Answer (score 8):

You need to think about two things:

1. Do you need to store props as state in the child components?
   **You might not need a state at all if it is directly derivable from props** – just use them directly:

   ```
   export default (props) => <Text>{props.myValue}</Text>
   ```
2. Do you need to update state if props change?

If the answer to both questions is "yes", you need to update state in`useEffect`:

```
export default (props) => {
  const myValueFromProp = props
  const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState(myValueFromProp)

  useEffect(() => {
     setMyValue(props)
  }, [...props])

  return (
    <Text>
     {myValue}
    </Text>
  )
}
```

Comment: mate why does this happen? I thought when new `props` will arrive, my component's logic will be reexecuted and `useState` will be triggered again with new value

Comment: @godblessstrawberry only if the reference of props changes